# Example of NSTask performing complex pipelines

Tags: objective-c, nstask

Can someone post code to show this?

Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find some NSTask / NSPipe sample code (and further references) here:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSPipe